# How to setup Eclipse EGit to connect to the MS Team Foundation Server without authentification error?

Tags: eclipse, git, tfs, egit

I am running a Ubuntu x64 in a VM. In the company network is a TFS which holds git repositories. When using git via command line I can easily clone the repros? When switching to Eclipse and using EGit it fails with:

```
"http://tfs:8080/tfs/myPrj: authentication not supported:
http://tfs:8080/tfs/myPrj: authentication not supported"
```

When I install the MS TFS Eclipse plugin I get the same error. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please show the JGit code that you use to connect.

Comment: How can I get this printout?

Comment: Are using EGit, the Eclipse plug-in. or JGit the Java library?

Comment: It is the EGit plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Alex Rukhlin's reply in [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f777613f-6d14-447d-93a9-c3d56293ee15/tee-authentication-not-supported?forum=tee):

> The fact that EGit Import Wizard cannot clone the Git repository from
>   TFS, either tells me that the issue is in that JGit functionality that
>   both (TEE and EGit) wizards use.
>
> We're digging into the problem trying to figure out if it's fixed in
>   some of recent EGit/JGit versions.

Comment: any idea when it should be fixed?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Please pay attention on the following versions.